# Pandas Setting a flag for if value in a column is null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to build this on Python using an IF loop. For every value in index if there is at least one value in Scancode column, then I want to set the Flag to okay, else blank.

| Index | Scancode | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21-5447 |  | blank |
| 21-5447 |  | blank |
| 21-5450 | 45e7-4731-8467-1ccfd67ef9a9.1.1 | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 | 4567-9093-826a0332f564.1.1 | okay |
| 21-5450 | 45c6-886b-070fa7ff121e.1.1 | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5450 |  | okay |
| 21-5452 |  | blank |
| 21-5452 |  | blank |
| 21-5454 | 45e7-4731-8467-1ccfd67ef9a9.1.1 | okay |
| 21-5454 |  | okay |
| 21-5460 |  | blank |
| 21-5460 |  | blank |

You can now import Markdown table code directly using File/Paste table data... dialog.

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop? Use the built-in functions of pandas.

Comment: `df[df['Scancode'].str != '']['Flag'] = 'okay'`

Comment: Because my flag is also dependent on the index column. If for a particular index value , we have at least one Scancode code value, then flag should be Okay for all rows of the corresponding index value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index('Index')
df.loc[df.groupby('Index').filter(lambda x: ~x['Scancode'].isna().all()).index, 'Flag'] = 'okay'
df['Flag'] = df['Flag'].fillna('blank')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                Scancode   Flag
Index                                          
21-5447                              NaN  blank
21-5447                              NaN  blank
21-5450  45e7-4731-8467-1ccfd67ef9a9.1.1   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450       4567-9093-826a0332f564.1.1   okay
21-5450       45c6-886b-070fa7ff121e.1.1   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5450                              NaN   okay
21-5452                              NaN  blank
21-5452                              NaN  blank
21-5454  45e7-4731-8467-1ccfd67ef9a9.1.1   okay
21-5454                              NaN   okay
21-5460                              NaN  blank
21-5460                              NaN  blank
```